# Как вывести две модели в Gridview

Tags: yii2

Eсть две модели `Goods` и `AddFeild`. `Addfeild` связана с Goods полем `id_good` связью `hasMany` есть необходимость вывести через `Gridview` содержание модели `Goods`, и все данные связанной модели `Addfeild`. Не подскажите как это можно реализовать. Или где найти как это реализовано.

Comment: В одной таблице, я такого не встречал. Обычно делают ссылку на ссылающуюся модель. А Addfeild дальше например в popUp показывать. Хотя можете добавить допустим accordeon в ячейку и там показывать данные(но нужно понимать что от этого вся таблица поедет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если дружишь с английским, и готов выдержать не очень сильный акцент индуса, то есть видео где он используя расширение kartik\dynaimid-forms создает модель po, а при нажатий на модель выводит связанные модели po_items.

Part 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqFpTBr323Y&list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF&index=28

Part 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAg0LIrZDdk&list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF&index=29